# Binding checkbox selections inside ng-repeat table with filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to implement checkboxes for selection of table rows.  The table is built with ng-repeat, and I'd like to include a text input to filter the table.  When a checkbox is selected, the ID for that item is pushed to an array and it's removed when the box is unchecked.  My issue is that after manipulating the filter, the checkboxes do not stay checked.  How do I properly bind the checkboxes to my array?

Plunk - https://plnkr.co/edit/U0N3vDTZAULC6CFIdhVp?p=preview

HTML:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names | filter: search">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="input-sm" ng-checked="selectedNames.indexOf(name.id) > -1" ng-click="addName(name.id)"/>
      </td>
      <td>{{name.name}}</td>
      <td>{{name.age}}</td>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.addName = function (id) {
    var idx = selectedNames.indexOf(id);
    if (selectedNames.indexOf(id) == -1) {
      console.log('Pushing: ', id)
      selectedNames.push(id);
      console.log(selectedNames);
    } else {
      selectedNames.splice(idx,1);
      console.log(selectedNames);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code a bit, and now it works fine. Here is working plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/8Jg9hvxibYhVV89Q0bts?p=preview

This code was added in controller:

```
  $scope.checkSelected= function(id){
    var idx = selectedNames.indexOf(id);
    return idx > -1;
  }
```

And I changed your ng-check expression:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-sm" ng-checked="checkSelected(name.id)" ng-click="addName(name.id)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend it taking your checkbox input and actually binding it to the model using ng-model:

```
<input ng-model="name.checked" type="checkbox" class="input-sm"/>
```

In this way, when you check the item it will remain with the `names` array no matter what you do, whether it's moving it around or adding elements to it or regenerating the table, the item will keep its `name.checked` attribute. The problem you will run into, however, is that you can't use the `ng-checked` attribute with `ng-model`, so to fix this we need to change your `selectedNames` array to be calculated when it is needed.

Say you need your selectedNames array:

```
//First, inject the $filter object into your angular controller
$scope.getSelected = function() {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.names, {checked: true}); // Or something along these lines. I'm just typing this into stack overflow so I haven't tested it.
}
```

Now, you don't have to call a script each time you select a name. It will be retrieved when you need the selected items.

Note: You can also use `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` to change around what the true/false values are equal to when the checkbox is checked/not checked.